# Attempting to solve for reaction forces in a beam results in a singular matrix

Tags: statics

I am attempting to solve for the reaction forces in the following beam, and set the equations up as an Ax=B system. Currently I have four equations for the four unknown reaction forces. Are my equations linearly dependent? - I simply wrote a sum of moments at each reaction force. I did not include a sum of forces equation - which should seem to be an obvious valid equation to use. The A matrix of my Ax=B system comes back as singular, thus I cannot find the inverse and solve the system. Could this system be statically indeterminate? The lengths a,b,c, etc are all equal, but F' is larger than F''.

[image]

Comment: Does the problem assume that left-right motion is zero? If so, the only degree of freedom of the beam are up-down motion and clockwise-counterclockwise motion. So, trying to uniquely solve for four support force probably means that you have infinite possible solutions

Comment: There are 5 degrees of indeterminacy, you need to find one more equation.

Comment: Why don't you show the equations in the question?